# Core Data Syncing with Ensembles: Failed to merge: The operation couldn’t be completed. (CDEErrorDomain error 204.)

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-drive, ensembles

I am experiencing the same problems outlined outlined in [this bug report](https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles/issues/176). I too synced my data with an old model version, and now I cannot sync again.

I completed the troubleshooting steps in that bug report:

- Deleeched my ensemble
- Deleted the Core Ensembles data in
  `~/Library/Mobile Documents` on my Mac and waited a few minutes to make sure it didn't come back
- Downloaded my container from my phone, deleted everything in 
  caches (`AppData/Library/Caches`, 
  `AppData/Library/Preferences/com.mentalfaculty.ensembles.eventdata`, and `AppData/Library/Application Support/<my bundle id>/com.mentalfaculty.ensembles.eventdata`)
- Deleted my saved iCloud ubiquity token from the app's plist (for good measure)
- Replaced the container on my phone with the modified container after deleting the caches

On trying to sync again, I am still getting `Failed to merge: The operation couldn’t be completed. (CDEErrorDomain error 204.)`

Since the error message is still "Error in Merge", though, I assume I'm not deleeching or otherwise getting rid of all my Ensembles data somewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you deleeched on your iPhone, and didn't leech again? And you don't have any other devices or simulators that could be putting the data back?

Comment: @DrewMcCormack That's correct - when I turn on syncing again after deleeching is when I get "error in merge". There are no other devices or simulators holding on to the data, this is my personal iCloud account, only logged into my personal phone and Mac.

Comment: Hmm, the data must be sticking around somewhere. Perhaps in the cloud. Or could it be when you put back the data? You should not put back the ensembles caches, or Mobile Documents. Ah, now I see. You should not put back `Application Support/<your bundle id>/com.mentalfaculty.ensembles.eventdata`. (Also nuke that folder on all devices for good measure.)

Comment: Hey @DrewMcCormack I forgot to mention I had done that previously (added to the question) - this time I also deleted all the data in all the simulators and also noticed some data was sticking around in iCloud -> Manage Storage -> (my app name). I deleted it there, and I think it's working. Thank you!